# React / Jest: how to test store.dispatch is called

Tags: redux, jestjs, redux-mock-store

I am new in Redux and Jest and I am struggling on a problem. I want to write the test for this file:

`eventListeners.js`

```
import store from '@/store';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  if (request.type === 'OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED') {
    store.dispatch(completeLogin());
  }
});
```

I have this file:

`eventListeners.test.js`

```
 it('dispatches completeLogin when OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED received', () => {
    // I have made a mock of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` so the listener defined in eventListeners.js is called when doing that
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED' });

    // I want to test that store.dispatch got called
  });
```

However I don't succeed to test that the `dispatch` method of the store is called.

**What I have tried so far:**

1) trying to mock directly the method dispatch of the store (eg. doing `jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch')` , `jest.mock('@/store')`).

However nothing seems to work. I think it is because the store used in `eventListeners.js` is not the one in the specs. So, mocking it does not do anything

2) Using the `redux-mock-store` library, as described in https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests .

Doing

```
const store = mockStore({})
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED' });
expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'LOGIN_COMPLETE' }])
```

However, same issue (I guess): the store used in the spec is not the same as in the `eventListeners.js` . `store.getActions()` returns `[]`.

Is there a good way to test that `store.dispatch` get called?

===================================

For now, what I do is that I subscribe to the store and I try to see if the store has change. As described in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/546

```
it('dispatches completeLogin when OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED received', () => {
    const storeChangedCallback = jest.fn()
    store.subscribe(storeChangedCallback)
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'OAUTH_SESSION_RESTORED' });
    expect(storeChangedCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

Is there a better way? Did I missed something?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I would like to know as well. If you mock dispatch then no matter what action is dispatches it will have been called with a `[Function anonymous]`